# How can I monitor vpn tun close event?

Tags: android, vpn, tun

About android vpn service .
When I start my vpn app and start vpn,  then start another vpn app and start vpn, my app's tun network interface is closed, bug my app's vpnservice is runing normally, why?

I want to know is there any method can let me know:my vpn's fd should close.
Two may sulution:

1. monitor network change event, can found that tun is closed.
2. when another vpn established, my vpnservice received onDestroy callback . ---acturally onDestroy is not called.

Comment: I use detachFd.

Comment: If I don't use detachFd, when tun is closed,  my vpnservice will  be called onDestry. But I find that Clash-Android also using detachFd, it onDestroy called immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason:

```
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return Binder()
    }
```

Nomally onBind should be :

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && SERVICE_INTERFACE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        return new Callback();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I found that?
When another vpn app called prepare, the vpn service should stop,but I find a logcat:
`oneway function results for code 16777215 on binder at 0xb40000730f64d060 will be dropped but finished with status UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION`
It seems that the binder has error, so I go to check the onBind implmentation.

Answer (score 1):

vpnservice onDestroy isn't supposed to be called when tun is closed.
vpnservice's [onRevoke](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService#onRevoke()) will be called if another app creates a vpn tun for device.

```
@Override
public void onRevoke() {
    super.onRevoke();
    //here is the event
}
```

Comment: Do you releally test your code? I remember that fd is not bean closed when the tun is closed.

Comment: onRevoke is called when user abort the app's vpn permission. "Invoked when the application is revoked. At this moment, the VPN interface is already deactivated by the system. The application should close the file descriptor and shut down gracefully. The default implementation of this method is calling Service#stopSelf()."

Comment: thanks for your answer, the reason I have found.It's my mistake, I override VpnService's onBind fun by carelessly.